# addObject to NSMutableArray doesn't work with storyboards

Tags: objective-c, arrays, storyboard, nsmutablearray

I have a table in my root view controller which has the "add" button mapped to another view controller which has text field to input the name of the list and a save button. That save button is mapped back to the main controller. When the data is passed back to the main controller, it doesn't add the item to the table.

This is what my table view controller's viewDidLoad look like:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

     if (!self.listArray) self.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [self.listArray addObject:@"New Item"];
     [self.tableView reloadData];

     [self updateButtonState];
  }
```

This adds the "New Item" to the list and shows up in the table. But when I pass the listname from the segue, I can see the log entry "Adding..." but doesn't add the item to the table. Here's the method for add a new item from a segue.

```
-(void) addList:(NSString *)listName
{
   NSLog(@"Adding %@", listName);
   [self.listArray addObject:listName];
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Prepare for segue

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     LSNewListViewController *sourceView = [segue sourceViewController];

     LSMainViewController *destView = [segue destinationViewController];
     [destView addList:[[sourceView listName] text]];
  }
```

Comment: can you post where you're using the addList: operation?

Comment: I just updated it....

Comment: What do you see if you log the value of `self` in both the `viewDidLoad` and the `addList:` methods?  (I'm wondering whether there's more than one `LSMainViewController` being created somehow.)

Comment: What are you returning in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method? Also, try logging the `listArray` in the main controllers `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: i'm not sure if this will help, but why not just take out the LSMainViewController *destView = [segue destinationViewController]; and do [segue.destinationViewController addList:[[sourceView listName] text]];

Comment: It looks like it's creating a new instance of the MainVC. I am not sure if this is related to how I'm doing storyboards.

Comment: It sounds like you may be pushing another VC onto the stack with a segue. You want to pop the current VC to get back to the previous (main) VC.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a storyboard segue to push another view controller, try setting a protocol in your "add" view controller. Then set your "main" view controller as the delegate and handle the adding there. From there you can connect the "add" button to call the delegate method and pop the view controller.

#### LSNewListViewController.h

```
@protocol LSNewListViewControllerDelegate;

@interface LSNewListViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LSNewListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol LSNewListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didAddToList:(NSString*)item;

@end
```

#### LSNewListViewController.m

```
@implementation LSNewListViewController

// Hooked up to the Add button in the storyboard (touchUpInside)
- (IBAction)addToListAction:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didAddToList:)]) {
        [self.delegate didAddToList:[sourceView listName] text]];
    }
}

@end
```

#### LSMainViewController.h

```
#import "LSNewListViewController.h"

@interface LSMainViewController : UIViewController <LSNewListViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

#### LSMainViewController.m

```
@implementation LSMainViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LSNewListViewController *destView = [segue destinationViewController];
    destView.delegate = self;
}

// Delegate method
- (void)didAddToList:(NSString*)item {
    NSLog(@"Adding %@", listName);
   [self.listArray addObject:listName];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```